# Consumir un asp web service

Tags: c#, webservice

Tengo la siguiente problema.
Estoy trabajando con web services en c#. Me han entregado una url de un sevicio cual consumir pero es muy diferente a los demás que he trabajado (al parecer esta desarrollada en asp).
La url no tiene wsdl(Web Services Description Language). El único detalle que me han dado son los parámetros y el tipo de dato que recibe, y que debe ser consumido de tipo SOAP.

- usuario:string
- password:sringe
- etc...

Cuando pongo la url en el navegador solo me da un error.
[image: Error de servicio]
EL uri de la dirección tiene el siguiente formato: 

http://servidor.org/carpeta/servicio.asp

Alguien ya ha consumido con este tipo de servicio, que me puedan brindar su ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo haría es revisar a través de una petición GET o POST qué retorna la página .ASP para consumir esos datos en la app.

Si es un web service SOAP debería tener un WSDL, puede ser que solo sea una página ASP.

Saludos,

Comment: He usado el SoapUi y me sigue enviando la misma respuesta. Que da pensar que mis credenciales estan mal, pero si solo envio usuario y pass me arroja otro error. Seguiré buscando.

Comment: Si envías la url del servicio te podríamos ayudar mas, saludos